# importXML in google spreadsheet two separated tags

Tags: xml, api, google-sheets

one more problem. I have following structure of XML:

```
<player>
 <id>12</id>
 <name>pl_name</name>
 <experience>
  <points>147</points>
  <level>10</level>
 </experience>
 <skills>
  <fight>0.00</fight>
  <defend>3.45</defend>
 </skills>
</player>
```

i want to be written just two tags. Lets say fight skill and level in my gdoc. so something like this:

```
=ImportXML("http://api.mysite.net/xml/user/id/"&C5; "/*(what here?)")
```

If it's possible :) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "query" argument of the ImportXML is an XPATH query. To get the experience level of the player you have several routes.  The easiest to understand is

```
=ImportXML("http://api.mysite.net/xml/user/id/"&C5; "/player/experience/level")
```

Another alternative, taking into account that the `level` element has a unique name, is this:

```
=ImportXML("http://api.mysite.net/xml/user/id/"&C5; "//level")
```

Both of those formulas would return `10` as the answer based on the XML that you gave.